# Browsers not able to stream video in ubuntu

Tags: 18.04, video, youtube

I am using Ubuntu 18.04, I am not able to stream any video in the browser from youtube, udemy or any other site, I have tried chrome and firefox. Although the video is loading the only issue is with streaming.

[image]

Comment: Can you please explain what do you mean by "the video is loading but not streaming"? In my mind they're the same thing.

Comment: @spacelander: I mean it's downloading the data but not able to stream it. I can see data loaded (buffered) on progress bar but it is always loading icon on video.I am not able to play.

Comment: @spacelander: I have updated a question with image.

Comment: Also it would be wise to point out that clicking at any point on the timeline of the video shows the picture of the video with no actuall video playing.

In my case all that have to be streammed does not work, video, audio.

Answer (score 0):

Install the `ubuntu-restricted-extras`. It contains the necessary codecs.

Comment: I have tried but It didn't worked

Comment: I have the exact same Issue, it did't worked

Comment: @Ruggi, I have to format and reinstall ubuntu in order to resolve the problem, no solution worked for me.

Comment: Oh man, that is the worst, its my job computer, I'll not be able to format it...